# How to enable SSH access using root account

Tags: server

I have enabled the password for root using the command #passwd root and now I want to connect to the server via SSH as root. I am unable to do this and somehow the root account cannot be accessed via SSH. What is the name of the file I have to edit and allow root login.

I have Ubuntu server 10.04 LTS

Comment: You really shouldn't use the root account. It's one of the main security principles that Ubuntu uses. Instead, you should use a standard user account and use the `sudo` command. Is there a reason you need the root account?

Comment: Agreed - Every hacker knows that a computer running GNU/Linux has a "root" account - so now they have to guess one less thing in order to log into your system. If you're using passwords, that's even worse.

Figure out what you want to do, and make an account that does only that - and you can use SSH keys, this allows for automation.

Comment: another vote for leaving root ssh access disabled - ssh in using a regular user and use sudo or su after you're logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed the SSH server on your machine? [Here](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/03/enable-ssh-secure-shell-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/) is a brief tutorial. You will need to edit the file /etc/ssh/sshd_config